# Multiple Azure IoT device identities through single gateway (MQTT)

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-digital-twins

i have a task that i would like to get insights from people with experience within IoT and Azure.

In the theoretical facility i have a PLC set-up which pulls the data from devices and stores them in a single data block with different node IDs (each node represents single device and holds measure values).
The PLC would connect to Azure IoT hub through a dedicated gateway (i.e. single connection string and single identity) hence the gateway would be registered as a single device in IoT hub.

Question: is it possible to setup separate device identities within Azure purely based on incoming data (node ids) instead of actual device connections so that IoT hub can recognize this as multiple devices instead of single device (gateway) with multiple data points? Reason for this is i want to be able to utilize Azure digital twin functionality and represent the data on per-device basis.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What you are describing is a gateway with identity translation. Can you check if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654740/azure-iot-edge-module-identity-translation-for-virtual-downstream-devices/62690474#62690474) is what you mean? This might be a duplicate.

Comment: Hope you are looking of Identity translation which is offered in Azure IoT Edge. You can have IoT edge modules running in your  gateway which accepts data from PLC and push it to Azure Iot Hub. Its is documented here   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-as-gateway.